# Monitor Linux services with Nagios 4

Tags: monitoring, nagios, service

I'm trying to monitor a few RHEL7 services via Nagios. I'd like to monitor if the services are running or stopped and receive an alert when stopped. I haven't any out of the box option with Nagios 4 and nagios-stat, which is the way we were doing it on our old Nagios server hasn't been updated for years.

EDIT: I decided to go with NRPE but can't figure out a working command for virt-who. The ps info for virt-who is this:

`root     60804  0.3 29.2 921684 548544 ?       S    Oct09   5:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/virt-who/virt-who.py -b`

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't keep running nagios-statd everywhere, if that's what you're comfortable with. It hasn't been updated in 9 years, though...

Comment: I'm not comfortable with it, it was done by someone else that is no longer part of the team. I prefer to avoid if there is another way to do it.

Comment: What type of service.  You just need to come up with a command line script tool that will test if something is good or not then returns a useful exit code.  Making your own scripts is really easy.  Though there huge numbers of example scripts to be found on the internet if you just search for 'nagios check {service name}'.

Comment: The service in question is virt-who but I'll apply the same check to monitor other services.

Comment: `systemctl show <servicename>` will give you all the information you could possibly want in an easy to parse format.

Answer (score 1):

You may try installing the NRPE together with the nagios plugins in the monitored server.
The simplest way to check whether a process is running is to add something like the following line inside nrpe.conf:

```
command[check_myprocess]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C myprocname -a stringinmyprocargs
```

Then you can add the following inside your Nagios server conf:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         
        host_name                       myservername
        service_description             myprocess
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_myprocess
        }
```

This should definitely work for Nagios version 3 and 4.

Comment: But this will tell me if the process is running, it will not tell me the status of my service, correct?

Comment: I'm trying your method but Nagios is returning an unknown response. Maybe I'm not using the right process name, this is the virt-who details:  
`root     60804  0.3 29.2 921684 548544 ?       S    Oct09   5:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/virt-who/virt-who.py -b`

Comment: Then you can use something like: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C python -a virt-who

Comment: it returns "unable to read output"